# How to Resolve CORS Issues When Accessing the API for Songs Search with only javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a web application that uses the Deezer API to search for songs by artist or song name. However, I'm encountering CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues that are preventing me from making successful requests to the API. Here's what I've tried so far:

I attempted to access the API directly, but I received a CORS-related error indicating that the required 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is missing from the response.
To overcome this, I used the https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ proxy before the API URL. However, I now get a "403 Forbidden" error with the message: "See /corsdemo for more info".
I also experimented with the no-cors mode in the fetch request, but this led to a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S'" error.
Here's the relevant function in my code:

```
async function getMoreSongs(url) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${url}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  showData(data);
}
```

I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to resolve these CORS issues and successfully retrieve song data from the Deezer API. Is there a proper way to use a CORS proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ in this case

[this is a pic for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmQA0.png)

Comment: The proxy (or *some* proxy, not necessarily that one) is your only choice, unless you can get the Deezer people to open up their API to any source URL (not likely).

Comment: And did you "see /corsdemo for more info"? What did you find out from that documentation?

Comment: You can't change CORS settings from browser code. That would make CORS policies useless. You need modifications outside the browser code, either a browser extension, a proxy or configurations on the server